# Windows 8.1 stuck on security setup

Tags: windows-8, security, windows-8.1, windows-8-upgrade, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have a new laptop Lenovo with already Windows 8 installed.
I have made the upgrade to Windows 8.1

After the upgrade was complete, i have made some basic configurations and then i arrived at the step where i am asked to insert a phone or an alternate email address.
And i can't go on.

The title is:  **Help us to protect your account**.
There is the possibility to insert a **phone**, an **alternate email address**, or '**skip this for now**'.
Whatever i do i cannot go on...

If insert a phone number and press **NEXT** then it returns to the same screen...
If i insert an email or i press 'skip this for now' it apply the same pattern: it just return to the same screen.

What can i do to pass the step?
Someone else did have the same issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok i have resolved.
Was not possible to continue from the upgrade step by step setup.
So i went into account.live.com using another pc, and setup there the phone and alternate mail.
Then come back to the Windows 8.1 upgrade and this time i was able to continue

Comment: post your comment as answer and mark it as answer.

Comment: I wanted to do so, but i miss two points of reputation to be able to do that..

Comment: ok, I voted for you, now you have 13 points Does it work now to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have resolved.

Was not possible to continue from the upgrade 'step by step' setup.

**So i went into account.live.com using another pc, and setup there the phone and alternate mail for my Microsoft account.**

Then come back to my new laptop, with Windows 8.1 upgrade "blocked", and this time i was able to continue.